# Incidence matrix from event list

Tags: r

I have a *huge* list of events in the following format:

```
> dput(head(events))
structure(list(action = c("110:0.49,258:0.49", "110:0.49,258:0.49", 
"110:0.49,258:0.49", "114:1.0,299:1.0", "114:1.0,299:1.0", "110:0.49"
), response = c("113=5-110=266-111=30-258=248-99=18-264=15", "113=5-110=278-111=30-258=260-99=18-264=15", 
"113=5-110=284-111=30-258=266-99=18-264=15", "114=34-299=34-108=134-110=12-246=67", 
"114=34-299=34-108=134-110=18-246=67", "114=34-113=6-299=34-108=146-110=24-246=73"
)), .Names = c("action", "response"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

both `action` and `response` are maps from keys like `110` and `114` to values like `0.49` and `5`.

What I want is a matrix whose `(i,j)` entry is `sum(action[i] * response[j])` over all events, where `action[i]` is the value for the key `i` (and similarly for `response`).  Additionally I would need the vectors `sum(action[i])` and `sum(response[j])`.

I can do that using something like this:

```
# split actions
l <- strsplit(events$action,",")
ll <- sapply(l,length)
l <- unlist(l)
l1 <- strsplit(l,":")
rm(l)
df1 <- data.frame(response = events$response[rep(1:nrow(events), ll)],
                  action = as.factor(sapply(l1,"[[",1)),
                  action.weight = as.numeric(sapply(l1,"[[",2)))

# split responses
l <- strsplit(df1$response,"-")
ll <- sapply(l,length)
l <- unlist(l)
l1 <- strsplit(l,"=")
rm(l)
rows <- rep(1:nrow(df1), ll)
df2 <- data.frame(action = df1$action[rows],
                  action.weight = df1$action.weight[rows],
                  response = as.factor(sapply(l1,"[[",1)),
                  response.weight = as.numeric(sapply(l1,"[[",2)))
df2$weight <- df2$action.weight * df2$response.weight
df2$action.weight <- NULL
df2$response.weight <- NULL

# summarise by action/response
dt1 <- as.data.table(df2)
setkeyv(dt1,c("action","response"))
dt2 <- dt1[, sum(weight), by="action,response"]
```

I think this should be more or less what I need.

However, the intermediate objects (`df1`, `df2`, `l`, &c) are far too large for my RAM.
I wonder if there is a way to accomplish what I need in a more efficient way.

PS. The sets of keys for `action` and `response` are, in fact, identical, but there seems to be no reason to rely on this.

Comment: it looks like this is a bit cumbersome, but I would begin with something like `events[, list(strsplit(action, ":,"), 
          strsplit(response, "-"))]`  (where `events <- as.data.table(events)`).

Comment: I'm not sure, but it seems like you should add `options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` at the top. `l <- strsplit(df1$response,"-")` fails when `response` is a factor...

Comment: @Frank: no, the weights *CANNOT* be assumed to be the same.

Comment: @sds Ah ok, I had mistakenly thought they were in your example. Oops. I should probably go ahead and delete that comment, then.

Comment: @sds when you say "square matrix", you're implying that the unique keys (110, 114) are *exactly* the same in both columns (action and response), right?

Comment: @Ferdinand.kraft: I do, but there is no reason to rely on that. I will remove the word "square". Thanks.

Comment: Don't store `response` in `df1` or `action` in `df2` - just store the row number (e.g. using `melt(strsplit(events$action, ','))`)and then merge together at a later stage. That should decrease your RAM usage quite a bit.

Comment: @eddi: how do I merge them by row?

Comment: @sds save the row numbers, e.g. the way I indicated above, and merge by that